# Recursion in Java method

Tags: recursion, methods, sequential

Here's the code

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class RecursionTest2
{
public static BigInteger fact(int n)
{
    System.out.println(n);
    BigInteger ans = BigInteger.ONE;
    if (n > 0) {
      ans = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
      ans = ans.multiply(fact(n-1)); 
    }
    System.out.println(ans);
    return ans; 
}



public static void main(String [] args)
{
    System.out.println("fact(50) = " + fact(50));
}
}
```

I have to derive a linear recursive formula for pow(2,n).
n has to = 80.

Then I have to implement a sequential program method in the same program.

Could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Can you please explain what you've done so far and why do you think its a problem?

Comment: @Phani what I have above is the code, but I have to implement the methods that I listed. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: "I don't know how to do that" is not a problem description fitted to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and
[how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Note the common features: factorial and exponentiation both use repeated multiplication.  The basic difference is that factorial multiples by N, repeating N times; exponentiation multiplies by the *base*, repeating N times.

Can you carry that hint far enough to write some code?  That gets you to a paradigm with which we're more comfortable.